Shri Vishnu and Mata Parvati
I came across an article with a very weird title: The Tale of Lord Vishnu and his consort Parvati
It mentions stories I have never heard or read about in any sources. So I wanted to know whether there is any truth to this (as in are this mentioned in any sources) to this stories or the writer here simple mistyped Vishnu in place of Shiva. Because to the best of my knowledge I am sure I have read multiple times that Shri Hari and Mata Parvati are considered sibilings. Or is it maybe another goddess with the same name. ( I have read that Dharma too has a wife named Lakshmi who is different from the one we worship with Shri Hari).

Most of what is written over there is incorrect. Parvati is the wife of Shiva, not Vishnu. There is however, a (possibly interpolated?) story in Brahma-vaivarta Purana in which Parvati is attracted to Vishnu and takes birth as Jambavati, one of Krishna's wives.

I know that Mata Parvati is wife of Shivji and not Shri Hari. I am asking whether any of the stories given in the said article have any credibility or not(since no sources are given in it). You're right though a lot of Brahma vaivarta puran is inteerpolated (the critical edition is very different from the regular one).

I am not aware of any critical edition for the Brahma-vaivarta purana. Can you please direct me to it? As for your question, most of the stories in the link are incorrect to the best of my knowledge. However, other knowledgeable members may comment on this.

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.552557/page/n1/mode/2up  (Part 1)   https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.424444    (Part 2)                                                         This are not the only ones though.

Thanks, I will take a look at it.

I read that... I think its mistype most probably and the writter has made a new story.

I didn't read the preface. A friend of mine told me that this was a critical edition.
